# SQLITE on CONFLICT with multiple unique keys

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to get a counter-based table working with on conflict clause and seem to be hitting a problem.

My currently SQL schema is

```
create table "read_ratio" (
    "time_bucket"   integer,
    "property_id"   text,
    "view_counter"  integer default 0,
    "read_counter"  integer default 0,
    primary key ("time_bucket","property_id"),
    unique ("time_bucket","property_id")
);
```

I have tried doing it without primary key with the same results.

Queries I have tryed to execute and getting `Result: near "ON": syntax error` is:

```
INSERT INTO read_ratio (time_bucket, property_id, view_counter)
VALUES ((strftime('%s','now')/60/60/24), 'qwe', 1)
ON CONFLICT(time_bucket) DO UPDATE SET view_counter = view_counter + 1;

INSERT INTO read_ratio (time_bucket, property_id, view_counter)
VALUES ((strftime('%s','now')/60/60/24), 'qwe', 1)
ON CONFLICT(time_bucket, property_id) DO UPDATE SET view_counter = view_counter + 1;
```

Queries without on conflict clause do get inserted and constrain on unique works when trying again. But I can't seem to get it working with the conflict.

I tried almost the same thing in MySQL (its equivalent) and it worked:

```
insert into read_ratio (time_bucket, property_id, view_counter)
values (round(unix_timestamp()/60), 'a3dcb4d229de6fde0db5686dee47145d', 1)
on duplicate key update view_counter = view_counter + 1;
```

My SQLite version

```
➜ sqlite3 -version
3.29.0 2019-07-10 17:32:03 fc82b73eaac8b36950e527f12c4b5dc1e147e6f4ad2217ae43ad82882a88alt1
```

Comment: Your 1st query does not work because there is no unique constraint on `time_bucket` but the 2nd works fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gRtQrjsuTyMEFcxcY4XpAn/1 although you don't need `unique ("time_bucket","property_id")` since you have defined th eprimary key.

Comment: If the second one is giving a syntax error, I suspect you're not using the version of sqlite you think you are.